# Regex expression for the anystring_anynumber__c.anystring_anynumber__c format

Tags: regex

I want regex expression for supporting the below format:-

**anystring_anynumber__c.anystring_anynumber__c**

Please help as I am not an expert and blocked on this.

Comment: Please try at least a bit to understand how regex works. You do not provide what you have tried to solve the problem nor at which exact point you are stuck. Read more on how to write good questions here http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score 0):

```
([A-z]+[_ ]\d+[_]{2}[c][.][A-z]+[_ ]\d+[_]{2}[c])
```

This Pattern will match the following `anystring_345345__c.anystring_345345__c`

> `[A-z]+` Matches any string with 1 or more characters
>
> `[_]` or `[c]` or `[.]` These math the single characters
>
> `[_]{2}` Matches 2 of the single character
>
> `\d+` Matches 1 or more of any number